# Threejs orthographic camera viewport

Tags: javascript, three.js

I use orthographic camera and i struggle with correct viewport calculation.
I want to push camera to the left for 100px to render something else in extra area.

In the following example there's a rendered green cube (for which i want to fix my viewport) and red square (expecting result made with css).
I can't change canvas size - it has to be 100% width and 100% height.
Best solution so far was to add extra value to camera left like:

```
camera.left   = - frustumSize * correctionAspect + 10;
```

But of course it doesn't scale. Other solution was to calculate camera.left with different aspectRatio like in the commented code:

```
correctionAspect = (width + 200) / height;
```

But it doesn't work well either.

Example code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nydhjw

Comment: It is unclear what result you are trying to achive. Your #render div height and width are set to 100% and then you calculate your canvas size dependant on this. What I see in your demo (canvas taking up the whole screen) is what I would expect. Are you trying to overlay the #example div on top of the canvas? Or have them side by side? Why are you putting #example as a child of the #render div?

Comment: #example div is my expecint result - viewport moved a little bit to the left.
My canvas needs to stay 100% x 100% of this div